# dimensions of files combined in an RData file

Tags: r, csv

Do the dimensions of each file need to be the same if I write various CSV files to an RData file? eg

```
Users <- read.csv('/Users/AndyD/Desktop/Data/DeakinUsersData.csv')
PagePaths <- read.csv('/Users/AndyD/Desktop/Data/DeakinPageData.csv')
Goals <- read.csv('/Users/AndyD/Desktop/Data/Deakin_Goals.csv')
save(Users, PagePaths, Goals, file = "initState.RData")
```

I then load the RData file

```
load("initState.RData")
```

...and my routine falls over just wondering about the dimensions of each of the csv files?

I then use reactive binding ()

```
CVtune <- load('initState.RData')
makeReactiveBinding('CVtune')
```

Comment: It shouldn't have any bearing on it. The inputs to `save()` can be anything, vectors, data.frames, objects of several different classes and structures. It shouldn't make any real difference in most cases.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "my routine falls over just wondering about the dimensions of each of the csv files". The dimensions don't matter when using `save`. All objects in your `RData` will get loaded into the current environment. You can easily check with `ls()` before and after `load("initState.RData")`.

Comment: ??? In principle you should be able to save and load any set of objects, regardless of whether they are the same dimensions (or even all the same type of object).  Can you be more specific about what "falls over" means? (Error messages?) How does the reactive binding stuff come in???

Comment: ok good to know..it must be something else then

Comment: here is the code i am running for a shiny APP    source('init.R',local = T)

# load RData locally
#load("initState.RData")
# Server ------------------------------------------------------------------

server <- function(input, output,session) {
 
  CVtune <- load('initState.RData')
  makeReactiveBinding('CVtune')

Comment: You don't need to assign `load(...)` to anything. Just `load(...)` suffices. It will load the objects from the `RData` file into the current environment. See `?load`.